# Dataframe methods within SBT project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I have the following code that works on the **spark-shell**

```
df1.withColumn("tags_splitted", split($"tags", ",")).withColumn("tag_exploded", explode($"tags_splitted")).select("id", "tag_exploded").show()
```

But fails in **sbt** with the following errors:

```
not found: value split
not found: value explode
```

My scala code has the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Books").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
```

Can someone give me a pointer to what is wrong in the **sbt** enviroment?

Thanks

Comment: did you import `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

Comment: That helped thanks

Answer (score 2):

The split and explode function are available in the package  `org.apache.spark.sql` inside `functions`.

So you need to import both

```
org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split
org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
```

Or

```
org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Hope this helps!